# How to parse string variable to Datetime in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I am trying to convert the String variable to DateTime using the DateTime.parse() function. I am getting the string in variable in this format "00:00:00. But when parse function runs on it it says It is invalid Date Format.

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't include screenshots of code: copy paste the text of your code and also the text of the exception into your question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do by using DateFormat class.

```
DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat('hh:mm:ss');
DateTime time = timeFormat.parse(stoptimetodisplay);
```

Answer (score 0):

DateTime date = DateTime.parse('2012-02-27 '+ stoptimetodisplay);

2012-02-27 this is any dummy date to just complete the format

This solves my problem but I thought @KuKu solution is more precise..